# Getting MainWindow frame from Other Window

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls

So i am in some window2  from this window I tried get frame defined in MainWindow.xaml
by creating a object of Mainwindow and tried to Navigate to a page but program giving " null reference exception unhandeled by user code"

I used:

```
 public Window2()
  {
   }

 myfunction()
 {
 MainWindow rootwindow = new MainWindow();
  rootwindow.myframe.Navigate( new Page1());
  }
```

Comment: Are you intending to instantiate (i.e., create) a new MainWindow here? Would something like `MainWindow rootWindow = Application.MainWindow` work instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is *not* how you get the frame from another window, you are just creating a **new** window and try to access something which is not loaded yet as the window you just created has not even been shown yet.

You need a reference to your window, which you could get from `Application.Current.MainWindow` if you set that accordingly beforehand (e.g. in the `App` class). Or you could pass a reference to the main window in the constructor of your second window.

Comment: Window mainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow;

mainWindow doesnt have frame inits option